# Some questions about executing programs across multiple cores

Tags: c#, multithreading, multicore

I am trying to use threads to execute a single program multiple times (spreading the load across the cores). I have two cores, so I need to make two threads I guess. And when one thread finishes, that thread needs to be reused again to execute. How would I go about doing this im lost

Comment: Which part are you having problems with?  Create two `Thread`s, have each one run some work.  Perhaps they could take items of work from a `Queue`.  What work are the threads going to be doing?

Comment: They will be executing the program. So by having two threads, it will execute a .exe on two different cores. I am wandering, should I use the threadpool? or just create two threads? and if I create two threads, how do I know when one is finished?

Comment: @Joey G - Using `join` on a Thread allows your code to block until the joined thread finishes. [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95hbf2ta.aspx)

Comment: Next time try at least spending a few moments googling "C# parallel" so that you at least have the knowledge to form a real question.  About the best anyone can do with this is tell you to go read about the TPL (as Eric Lippert did below.)

Comment: @mquander, be nice... some people just have a hard time figuring out these concepts.

Answer (score 5):

Do not attempt to write the thread management code yourself. Use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx); that is precisely what it is for.

Based on the way you're asking the question, I suspect you do not have a very good understanding of how threads work. You might also be confusing threads with processes. Can you describe the work your program is doing in more detail?  It is possible that using multiple processes is the right way to go, but it seems more likely that you want to have one process with several threads.

Comment: Alright. Say I have a program that I want to execute a thousand times. I wanted to use a loop to assign the execution to threads so they would be spread across the cores so it would run faster instead of consecutively.

Comment: @Joey: The TPL is designed for that job. However, you should be aware that unless your program is "embarrassingly parallelizable", parallelization might not help, and might in fact make it slower. Some jobs are inherently easy to parallelize; If you are trying to analyze a thousand images and trying to identify each as being a picture of the Golden Gate Bridge or the Eiffel Tower, doing 500 images on each core is a great idea. If you're analyzing *one* image, doing the left half on one core and the right on another is a *terrible* idea.